# ansi-term no longer works when emacs is run in daemon mode

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

I shell into a remote server to run emacs using ssh. Ever since I started running emacs as a daemon I've been having problems using ansi-term, shell, and eshell.

I can run commands in `eshell` fine, but I can't switch back to another buffer or kill the eshell buffer. When I type these commands nothing happens.

When I run `shell` I can enter commands but everything shows up on the same line. If I have the screen split text from shell will run into my other window. Repeatedly pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes my PS1 to be displayed on the same line, rather than a new line. I also cannot kill the shell buffer or exit emacs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I have to type `exit` which kills my `ssh` session all together.

`ansi-term` is now the least useful as when I start it Emacs freezes. I can't enter any commands including killing emacs all together.

Has anyone had these problems before?

Comment: how are you connecting - Putty, command-line `ssh`, something else?

Comment: ssh from iTerm2